# How can I upload form/field contents to an IPFS node using Django?

Tags: python, django, port, ipfs

I'd like to override the upload behavior of a django ImageField so that after uploading to some url, the file will be added to an ipfs node.

For example, my model is something like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, blank=True)
```

I first try saving it as you would any other image, but then I give it an IPFS hash, which will allow the user to load the data client side.

In my views I have the following code to get an instance of ipfs daemon running.

```
import ipfsapi
from subprocess import call

os.system("ipfs daemon")
api = ipfsapi.connect('127.0.0.1', 5001)
```

When I try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` or `runserver`, however, the daemon runs but the rest of the command doesn't.

```
Initializing daemon...
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/174.56.29.92/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.1.109/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip6/::1/tcp/4001
API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080
Daemon is ready
```

How can I start an ipfs daemon and also a django server?  It doesn't look like they're listening on the same port (Django 8000, IPFS 8080), so why am I running into this problem?

Answer (score 1):

https://pydigger.com/pypi/django-ipfs-storage

### Installation

.. code:: bash

```
pip install django-ipfs-storage
```

### Configuration

By default `ipfs_storage` adds and pins content to an IPFS daemon
running on localhost and returns URLs pointing to the public
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/ HTTP Gateway

To customise this, set the following variables in your `settings.py`:

- `IPFS_STORAGE_API_URL`: defaults to
  `'http://localhost:5001/api/v0/'`.
- `IPFS_GATEWAY_API_URL`: defaults to `'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/'`.

Set `IPFS_GATEWAY_API_URL` to `'http://localhost:8080/ipfs/'` to
serve content through your local daemon’s HTTP gateway.

### Usage

There are two ways to use a Django storage backend.

As default backend
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Use IPFS as `Django’s default file storage
backend <https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE>`__:

.. code:: python

```
# settings.py

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'ipfs_storage.InterPlanetaryFileSystemStorage'

IPFS_STORAGE_API_URL = 'http://localhost:5001/api/v0/'
IPFS_STORAGE_GATEWAY_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/ipfs/'
```

For a specific FileField
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Alternatively, you may only want to use the IPFS storage backend for a
single field:

.. code:: python

```
from django.db import models

from ipfs_storage import InterPlanetaryFileSystemStorage 


class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    file_stored_on_ipfs = models.FileField(storage=InterPlanetaryFileSystemStorage()) 
    other_file = models.FileField()  # will still use DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
```

Comment: how do you configure this for say a heroku webserver, or AWS / Azure.  The URLs would be different sure, but what would it be to?

Comment: whether u can run an IPFS daemon on those servers will still be localhost otherwise is to have the ipfs daemon in another server and use the IP server there.... Good luck